# mysql GROUP_CONCAT + seaparator + order by?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat, separator

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  t.term SEPARATOR '' ORDER BY t.term )
```

Does not work, syntax problem. If I remove either of SEPARATOR or ORDER BY it works.
DISTINCT as it seems does not have any influence. Can't see reason why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  t.term ORDER BY t.term SEPARATOR '')
```

separator must come last, as it looks like